# Difference between <asp:table> and <table>?

Tags: asp.net

Guys What is a difference between both??

if I set `<table runat=server>` I can use it at server side also.

Is there any differnce between both??

Thanx

Comment: This question may help you understand more about these. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/57958/when-to-use-htmlcontrols-vs-webcontrols

Comment: I just use the HTML table version, as it gives a nice 3x3 grid to work on in the VSS designer screen. The asp version, I have to use properties to give it columns, rows, etc and *then* design around it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`<asp:Table>` is a .Net object that has specific properties and capabilities that can be utilized through .Net scripting or code behind logic. `<table>` is an Html element that can be accessed through scripting and code behind logic, but it has no native .Net capabilities and can only be output as is.

Comment: What do you mean by "no native .net capabilities?" How is `WebControls.Table` any more native than `HtmlControls.HtmlTable`?

Comment: @tenfour: Too much to put in a comment so I'll leave a link that breaks the ice on the differences. But there ARE differences. http://odetocode.com/articles/348.aspx

Comment: Of course there are differences. But not of the "more native than the other" type. Maybe you mean "abstracted from HTML".

Comment: @tenfour: I'd say this comes down to our probable difference in opinion on the definition of "native" as it applies in this context. I can accept that you don't agree with my characterization of the term as it applies here.

Answer (score 4):

`asp:table` lives in the [`System.Web.UI.WebControls`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.aspx) namespace - these are components that wrap around the different HTML controls and provide a familiar interface and usage to winforms developers (for a table, it will have a `Columns` attribute).

`table` lives in the [`System.Web.UI.HtmlControls`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/system.web.ui.htmlcontrols.aspx) namespace and is a direct analogue to the actual HTML controls and provides an interface more familiar to HTML developers (for a table, it will have a `Cols` attribute).

In terms of output, these pretty much behave the same way.

Answer (score 1):

- A `<asp:Table>` is an ASP.NET control
- A `<table>` is HTML.

Whenever you create an aspx, you're actually modify an XML document that has the representation of HTML - this can include both server side and client side tags.

Your typical web browser has no idea what a `<asp:Table>` is because it only understands HTML.  Therefore the server (ASP.NET) converts all server side tags into its HTML representation.  Therefore if you use your browser to view the source of a page that includes `<asp:Table>` you will only see `<table>` tags.

Comment: Correction: `<table>` doesn't run at all, as it's not executable code, just HTML formatting.

Comment: That's not true. You can easily add <table ruant="server"></table> and modify the table server-side as well.

Answer (score 0):

The `<asp:table>` represents the declarative syntax for the System.Web.UI.WebControls.Table class which is a WebControl. Being a WebControl, it has a much more powerful programming interface and
provides a more object like interface providing for a high level of control.

The `<table>` tag on the other hand when used with the runat="server" attribute represents the
System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlTable class which is a HtmlControl. Being a HtmlControl, it is very basic and provides much lesser programmatic control over it's properties.

Answer (score 0):

HTML elements in ASP.NET files are treated as text, server controls are treated as objects. To make these HTML elements server side programmable you can add a `runat="server"` attribute to the HTML element. The main difference between HTML table and `<asp:Table>` is the way they can be nested, created, bound and controlled at runtime as an object rather than a string of text.

More information can be found [here](http://www.asp101.com/lessons/webcontrols.asp).